# NATURAL JOIN vs WHERE IN Clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently, I dealt with retrieving a large amount of data which consists of thousands of records from a MySQL database. Since it was my first time to handle such large data set, I didn't think about the efficiency of the SQL statement. And the problem comes.

Here are the tables of the database
(It is just a simple database model of a curriculum system):

course:

```
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| course_id | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lecturer  | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| credit    | float               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| week_from | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| week_to   | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

select:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| select_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| card_no   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| course_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| term      | varchar(7)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When I want to retrieve all the courses that a student has selected (with his card number),
the SQL statement is

```
SELECT course_id, name, lecturer, credit, week_from, week_to
FROM `course` WHERE course_id IN (
    SELECT course_id FROM `select` WHERE card_no=<student's card number>
);
```

But, it was extremely slow and it didn't return anything for a long time.
So I changed `WHERE IN` clauses into `NATURAL JOIN`. Here is the SQL,

```
SELECT course_id, name, lecturer, credit, week_from, week_to
FROM `select` NATURAL JOIN `course`
WHERE card_no=<student's card number>;
```

It returns immediately and works fine!

So my question is:

- What's the difference between `NATURAL JOIN` and `WHERE IN` Clauses?
- What makes them perform differently?
  (Is that maybe because I doesn't set up any `INDEX`?)
- When shall we use `NATURAL JOIN` or `WHERE IN`?

Comment: `select` is an awfull name for a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically the two queries are equivalent. I think it's just poor implementation of the MySQL query optimizer that causes JOIN to be more efficient than WHERE IN. So I always use JOIN.

Have you looked at the output of EXPLAIN for the two queries? Here's what I got for a `WHERE IN`:

```
+----+--------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | t_users           | ALL            | NULL              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL       | 2458304 | Using where              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t_user_attributes | index_subquery | PRIMARY,attribute | PRIMARY | 13      | func,const |       7 | Using index; Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

It's apparently performing the subquery, then going through every row in the main table testing whether it's in -- it doesn't use the index. For the JOIN I get:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+---------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys       | key       | key_len | ref                                   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+---------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t_user_attributes | ref    | PRIMARY,attribute   | attribute | 1       | const                                 |   15 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t_users           | eq_ref | username,username_2 | username  | 12      | bbodb_test.t_user_attributes.username |    1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+---------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Now it uses the index.

Comment: The two queries are not equivalent. A JOIN will produce a different result than a sub-select.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If the subselect only returns one row per `course_id`, the two are equivalent. If it can return multiple rows, the join produces a cross-product while the where-in will only produce one row per course.

Comment: Exactly. And therefor those two statements are not the same thing (they apparently just happen to return the same result in this case which is not the same thing as "being equivalent"). They mean something fundamentally different and @rAy should be aware of that.

Comment: But if anything, the difference suggests that the WHERE IN should be _more_ efficient, since it doesn't have to produce a full cross-product. A good optimizer would get the list of results from the subquery, and then find each of them in the index of the main table.

Comment: The queries would be equivalent if you add `GROUP BY course_id` to the end of the JOIN. As far as I can tell, this makes no difference to the query optimizer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT course_id, name, lecturer, credit, week_from, week_to
FROM `course` c
WHERE c.course_id IN (
    SELECT s.course_id 
    FROM `select` s
    WHERE card_no=<student's card number>
    AND   c.course_id = s.course_id
);
```

Notice the addition of the AND clause in the sub-query. This is called a co-related sub-query because it relates the two course_ids, just as the NATURAL JOIN does.

I think Barmar's index explanation is on the mark.